# httpResponseMessage.TryGetContentValue not working

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2

Calling httpResponseMessage.TryGetContentValue is not behaving as expected.

I have a WebAPI method that returns an IHttpActionResult. If the user passes in the incorrect parameters, I want to send back a response with a custom message, so I have the following. Note where I add a message string to the Content property.

```
[HttpGet]
public IHttpActionResult ActionResultErrorTest(int id)
{
    var payload = "";
    if (id == 0)
    {
        var resp = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.NotFound)
        {
        Content = new StringContent(string.Format("No product with ID = {0}", id)),
            ReasonPhrase = "Product ID Not Found",

        };
        throw new HttpResponseException(resp);
    }

    payload = "Success";

    return Ok(payload);
}
```

So far, so good. Next, I have a DelegatingHandler that augments the response. In this code, I call the HttpResponseMessage.TryGetContentValue() extension method.
[Clarification on my Confusion]
For ActionResultErrorTest(0), the extension method returns false.
For ActionResultErrorTest(1), the extension method returns true.
I don't understand this since in both cases, the Content contains a string.

Here is the delegating handler code:

```
    protected override async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        //Step 1: Wait for the Response
        var response = await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
        if (request.RequestUri.AbsoluteUri.Contains("swagger"))
        {
            return response;
        }
        return BuildApiResponse(request, response);

    }

    private HttpResponseMessage BuildApiResponse(HttpRequestMessage request, HttpResponseMessage response)
    {
        object content;
        List<string> modelStateErrors = new List<string>();
        bool hasContent = response.TryGetContentValue(out content);
        string content2;
        bool hasContentString = response.TryGetContentValue<string>(out content2);
        string dialogTitle = "";
        bool preventUserInput = false;
...
```

In the above code, even though I set Content = "No product with ID = 0", content and content2 evaluate to NULL and hasContent and hasContent2 both evaluate to false

Comment: how about `await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync()`

Comment: Show the delegating handler